# Android Studio: App stops working after login

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, android-studio-3.0

So I am new to Android Studio and still learning. I am trying to create an application that allows the user to connect with his facebook and once he is logged in, he can move on to the profile page. his facebook UserID in the below example is passed on to the class profiles on success. However, after logging in with facebook, my application just crashes.. what am i doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LoginButton loginButton;
    TextView textView;
    String s;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                //textView.setText("Login success "+loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() +"\n"+loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                    s = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();

                        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,profiles.class);
                        i.putExtra("Id",s);
                        startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                textView.setText("Login Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

the profile part basically consists of 3 edittexts that allow the user to enter his information and it gets stored in realm database

```
public class profiles extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username,age,country;
Realm realm;
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.profile);
            Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
            final String userid;
            userid = bundle.getString("Id");
            username= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            age= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
            country= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);

            Realm.init(this);
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            findViewById(R.id.Continue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                        Users obj= realm.createObject(Users.class);
                        obj.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
                        obj.setCountry(country.getText().toString());
                        obj.setAge(age.getText().toString());
                        obj.setUserId(userid);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and here is the users class for getters and setters used,

```
public class Users extends RealmObject {
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        UserId= userId;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        Username = username;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }



    String UserId;
    String Username;
    String Country;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    String age;

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }



    public String getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the logcat output.

Comment: Its not showing any specific issue with the application. When I try to reopen my application, I notice that it works but it doesn't get directed to the profile page.. It remains on the main page and shows that the user has connected.

Comment: maybe using try catch statement for lines inside onCreate in profiles class will show you  which line creates an exception.

Comment: It should show logcat output.  logcat output may hidden in logcat filters: com.name.appname (20151 )[DEAD] application